# Express.js doesn't serve any of my static files

Tags: node.js, express

I'm facing a problem with express. It doesn't serve any static file !!
I tried so many solutions but no one works. this is the code

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express() 

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));

port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.listen( port, () => {
    console.log("running on port " + port )
})
```

I tried to make it

```js
app.use('public' , express.static(__dirname + 'public'))
```

and

```js
app.use('public' , express.static(path.join(__dirname , 'public')))
```

and

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname , 'public')))
```

but still not working !!
files structure is

```
|test==> project name 
  |public
    |_test.html
  |index.js
```

Comment: Your path is incorrect (missing a `/` before `public`. It's best to use `path.join()`, eg `express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))`

Comment: With the path fixed, you should be able to open `http://localhost:3000/_test.html` in your browser. Is that the URL you're trying to open?

Comment: I forgot to add / before 'public' but actualy I added it and still not working

Comment: How do you know it's not working? What are you trying to do, what do you expect to see and what do you actually see?

Comment: It works when I open http://localhost:3000/test.html but why it not working when I open just http://localhost:3000

Comment: Because you don't have an `index.html` file? Again, **what do you expect to see**?

Comment: ok I got it  thank you for your cooperation

Answer (score 2):

If your structure is like this:

```
|test==> project name 
  |public
    |_test.html
  |index.js
```

`__dirname` will give you the current directory name your `index.js` file is in, so it will not include another `/` at the end. You will need to add the public folder like this: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Or more simply you can use `app.use(express.static('public'))`

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration for Express' static *directory index* is `index.html`. If you want to use a different default (for example your `_test.html` file), you can configure it with the `index` option.

Also, as mentioned above, your path is incorrect; you are missing a `/` before `public`.

It's best to use `path.join()` for portability.

```js
const path = require("path")

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname , "public"), {
  index: "_test.html"
}))
```

Now you can open http://localhost:3000/ in your browser and Express will serve your `_test.html` file.

Answer (score -1):

You miss the / before public. try `path.join(__dirname, '/public')`

Comment: If you're using `path.join()`, you do not include the directory separators

Comment: thanks for the advice, im currently using / and it works for me, i think i should remove it

Comment: See https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathjoinpaths

Comment: I think the problem isn't because of / . I added it and still not working

Answer (score -1):

try this way :

```
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
```